# Memory allocation in Java - Declaration vs Definition

Tags: java, c

In C, when we declare something, we tell the compiler what type of thing the variable contains. Only during the definition do we allocate memory space for it. However, in Java, memory space is alloated when we declare a variable

```
int x; // allocates space for an int
```

Are my premises correct? Does that mean we should be a sparse with decalarations as possible?

Comment: (1) don't worry about this, you'll write horrific code if you do. (2) Are you only talking about primitives or both primitives and objects. (3) the only time this will ever matter is huge arrays and they are objects

Comment: I'm curious about both. But was I correct in saying that memory is allocated during declaration in Java, instead of during definition as in C?

Comment: What do you mean by definition and declaration? While it's technically true that a C declaration doesn't allocate anything, any (useful) declaration still needs a definition somewhere, and your examples code isn't a declaration in C (and while Java calls it a "declaration" it's actually the moral equivalent of a C definition; Java just doesn't have that distinction).

Comment: Well primatives (who cares, and I'm also not sure). The only thing thats going to be an issue are large arrays and objects; both of which have memory allocated with the `new`. After all int[][][] could have any size between 0 (well technically not exactly 0) and infinity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it comes to variables in Java, there is no separation between declarations and definitions. This does not influence memory allocation process, though.

What happens to memory allocations in Java is close to what happens to allocating memory from the dynamic area (i.e. "the heap") in C. There, defining a variable of pointer type allocates space for the variable itself, but it does not allocate memory for what the pointer points to. Here is an example of a simple string manipulation in C:

```
// Allocate memory for the pointer
char *str;
// Allocate memory for the string itself
str = malloc(16);
// Copy the data into the string
strcpy(str, "Hello, world!");
```

Similar things happen in Java when you deal with objects. Defining a variable allocates space for the object reference, but not for the object. You need to call `new` in order to "attach" that reference to a new object:

```
// Allocate memory for the reference
String str;
// Allocate memory for the string, and sets data
str = new String("Hello, world!");
```

Note that this applies only to objects. Primitive types are handled differently, in a way that is a lot more similar to the way the primitives are handled in C.

Answer (score 2):

The memory space for a primitive would be allocated when memory for the object instance is allocated. For a static primitive it would be allocated when the class is loaded.

No, you should not try to micro-optimize such things. This isn't C, it's Java.